# How to configure iTextSharp PDF to open with "Smooth Text" enabled by default?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe-reader

PDF text looks much better in Adobe Reader when `"Smooth Text"` is set to `"For Monitor"` instead of `"None"`.

I'm creating a PDF in `iTextSharp` that I would like to  open in PDF readers with smooth text enabled wherever possible.

I've searched for an answer in documentation and Stack Overflow without success.
I thought the `PdfWriter.ViewerPrefrerences` property might provide this functionality but I can't see that it does.

Comment: What is a PDF browser?

Comment: @Anil Sorry, I meant PDF reader.

Comment: I searched the PDF specification for "smooth text" but found nothing. Are you sure you are talking about a PDF related feature?

Comment: @mki Thank you for looking. In a PDF, preferences can be set for things like printer scaling, preferred page layout, toolbar visibility, etc but I don't know whether "smooth text" is a PDF related feature. What I am after may simply be impossible.